# Confused about visa question: “Voluntarily elected to depart the UK” ? Yes or No?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

I applied and successfully received a student visa from India in October 2017. I traveled to the UK on October 12, but could not register for the course. Since the latest registration date for my course, October 13, was already over, I left the UK willingly on the 16th. I did not collect my BRP from the university. Afterwards, I withdrew from the course and got the course withdrawal letter from UCAS and a full refund from the university for the tuition fees.

I have only received an email on March 23, 2018 from Home Office, which mentions that my previous Tier 4 visa has been curtailed, citing non-commencement of my studies with my university.

Now, I am applying for May 2018 intake for the same course at another university. I have already paid the full tuition fees and also received the CAS letter.

Since now I am submitting a fresh Tier 4 visa application, kindly guide me for replies to the following 2 questions mentioned in the application:

1. Have you ever been deported, removed or otherwise required to leave the UK? Yes/No
2. Have you ever voluntary elected to depart the UK? Yes/No. (If yes, what do I answer "under immigration decision and the papers you were served", and "reference number" as the reference number on email is given in form of XXXXXX1234).

Comment: Dual posting from Travel SE (where it has an answer): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112110/confused-about-visa-question-voluntarily-elected-to-depart-the-uk-yes-or-no